# Ajax and Security Pitfalls

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery, optimization

Some time ago I start to work with Ajax, and I realy want to learn the right way to use it. My websys load the content with Ajax but I noted that if I change the HTML link code in Chrome or any other Nav the requisition will be done any away. My question is what is the right way to secure and *verify the acess of links*, and how I can do that with **CI Framework** and **Ajax**. My idea is verify with session integrating that with ajax loading the content based on the permission of user, but I don't know where I put that code in MVC Controller structure and how integrated that with the view/Ajax. I appreciate if someone could share some example code because I don't have any clue to solve that puzzle.

Comment: Not sure I completely follow your specific question, but here is an old blog post I wrote that discusses some of the basic web form security mistakes - doing it with ajax is no different, really: http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/12/web-form-security-avoiding-common-mistakes might get you started on some questions

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I need to learn how to limit access of some links that are loading with Ajax.